# Ajax loading is not smooth in both .load() and .html() methods

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function load_content(url)  
{
  $('#loading').show();
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#target').html(data); 
    $('#loading').hide();  
  });  
}
```

I use the following code to load content from another page in to a `<div>` ID target. Until the content is get loaded the page becomes unresponsive or very slow in scrolling. Also the GIF preloader is not animating. I experienced the same issue while using the methos `.load()`. Any bad practice in my code? Or how to overcome this issue?

But in this site http://www.behance.net/ the Ajax loading of content on scroll is smooth. How to achieve the same?

I am facing this especially in Chrome. IE and firefox, it is smooth as I expect.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is somewhere else... Can we see this live somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` methods of jQuery:

```
function load_content(url){
   $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
       $('#loading').show();
   });

   $.get(url, function(data) {
       $('#target').html(data);
   });

   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
       $('#loading').hide();
   });

 }
```

### .ajaxStart()

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at this time.

#### [.ajaxStart() from docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

### .ajaxComplete()

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time.

#### [.ajaxComplete() from docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)